# Unable to Connect Emulator with localhost ? Android | Firebase

Tags: java, php, android, localhost

I am trying to save emulator's token number into localhost (wampserver-phpMyAdmin).

System is giving -> Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80

[here is full code link](https://github.com/satinderjg/GCMFirebase)

This is the function in which i tried to register my token

```
private  void registertoken(String token){

    Log.d(TAG, "registertoken: registion begins !!!!!!!! \n !!!!!!!!!!!!! ");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost/fcm/register.php")

            .post(body)
            .build();
   // http://fcm/register.php
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is PHP file I am using :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Token"])){
$token = $_POST["Token"];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");
$query = "INSERT INTO user(Token) Values ('$token') ON 
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$token' ; ";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

localhost will point to the emulator, not your pc.  you'll need to use the ip/dns address of the pc

Answer (score 1):

Use your pc's local ip address or can also try 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.